Why does MoleculeModify only accept a single modification?
MoleculeModifyis a powerful function to alter a chemical structure. However, it accepts only one modification, there is no (direct) way to give a list of consecutive modifications. For instance, in order to change all bonds to bond type "Single", you have to use e.g. Fold:
MakeSimple[mol_] := 
 Module[{kekMol = MoleculeModify[mol, "Kekulize"]},
  Fold[MoleculeModify[#1, {"SetBondType", #2 -> "Single"}] &, kekMol, 
   Values /@ 
    FindMoleculeSubstructure[kekMol, Bond[_, "Double"], All]]]

Is this statement true, or do I miss something?

I've tested the following in 13.2 so it works going back that far. This is a documentation bug that I never specifically wrote that it can modify a list of bonds:
In[1]:= MoleculeName@
 MoleculeModify[
  m = Molecule["benzene"], {"SetBondType", 
   Thread[BondList[m] -> "Single"]}]

Out[1]= "cyclohexane"

